# Unable to connect with Microsoft Exchange mail server using exchangelib in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exchange-server, office-automation, exchangelib

I am trying to connect with my official mail server using exchangelib library in python and getting the error

"HTTPConnectionPool (host='mail.domainnam.in', port=443): Read timed out. (Read timeout=120)"

```
def send_mail(content):
    # Load environment variables from the .env file
    load_dotenv()

    # Access environment variables
    outlook_user = os.getenv('OUTLOOK_USER')
    outlook_password = os.getenv('OUTLOOK_PASS')
    outlook_server = os.getenv('OUTLOOK_SERVER')
    outlook_email = os.getenv('OUTLOOK_EMAIL')

    credentials = Credentials(
        username=outlook_user,
        password=outlook_password
        )

    config = Configuration(
        server=outlook_server,
        credentials=credentials
        )

    account = Account(
        primary_smtp_address=outlook_email,
        config=config,
        autodiscover=False,
        access_type=DELEGATE
        )

    msg = Message(
        account=account,
        subject="Test Mail",
        body=content,
        to_recipients=["email_address_1"],
        cc_recipients=["email_address_2"]
        )
    msg.send_and_save()
```

I have tried this thread but none of the solution worked "https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/271"

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that `mail.domainnam.in` is where the Exchange EWS service is running? The error message indicates that nothing is answering correctly on that hostname and port.

Comment: I am using the correct server, just mentioned "mail.domainnam.in" to hide company server details,

Answer (score -1):

adjust the timeout settings in your exchangelib code.

```
config = Configuration(
    server=outlook_server,
    credentials=credentials,
    timeout=30  # Adjust the timeout duration as needed
)
```

Comment: It's showing no parameter named "timeout"